# Pandas check if required columns have data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation

I have two dataframes:

1. **df_data** which contain and ID column which link it to another dataframe (df_data_req) and other columns there contain some data. Not all columns would have data, which is ok in some cases.
2. **df_data_req** contains the same ID as in df_data, and in this dataframe it is specified which columns there should have data.

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['x','y','x','z'],
                   'col1':['1','','2','f'],
                   'col2':['5','5','5','5'],
                   'col3':['','1','3','5']})
df_data_req = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['x','y','z'],
                   'col1':['X','','X'],
                   'col2':['X','X','X'],
                   'col3':['X','X','']})
```

I would then like to validate all rows in df_data, and check (based in the ID column), if all columns there are specified in df_data_req have a value.

What I expected is addition column to df_data which indicate "Missing data" or "OK" which are depended on what there are specified in df_data_req. The output for the sample data would then be:

| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | validation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 5 |  | MissingData |
| y |  | 5 | 1 | OK |
| x | 2 | 5 | 3 | OK |
| z | f | 5 | 5 | OK |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach with `set_index`, `df.reindex_like` followed by conditional check:

```
a = df_data.set_index("ID").replace("",np.nan)
b = df_data_req.set_index("ID").replace("",np.nan)
c = a.fillna(b.reindex_like(a)).eq("X").any(1)
df_data['validation'] = np.where(c,"MissingData","OK")
```

---

```
print(df_data)

  ID col1 col2 col3   validation
0  x    1    5       MissingData
1  y         5    1           OK
2  x    2    5    3           OK
3  z    f    5    5           OK
```